# solve the differential equation $ y' +xy=c$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to solve differential equations but I think I am getting confused because there is a constant. I began by using integrating factors but when then  end up with a very complicated integral which doesn't seem right because the original equation seems pretty straight forward. Please help!

I used the integrating factor $\mu=e^{x^2/2}.$ After multiplying the entire equation by $\mu$ and integrating I end up with $e^{x^2/2}y= \int Ce^{x^2/2}\,dx.$

I apologize if the formatting is off. I haven't quite gotten the hang of this syntax.

Comment: Can you please show the work you have done?

Comment: I imagine you're having difficulty. That integral on the right has no antiderivative expressible with elementary functions. What context does this appear in?

Comment: what you have now is correct. there is no closed form expression for $\int e^{x^2/2} \, dx.$  you can pull the $c$ out and change the dummy integral variable to $t.$ make the integral definite say from $0$ to $x$ and add a constant.

Comment: It's probably better to leave it in that form. Get $y$ by itself on the left side and leave the integral alone.

Comment: the context is very hard to explain. I had to use a certain condition to prove that a different equation was exact. I ended up with the above equation and needed to apply the appropriate first order method to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[y]+xy=c $$
Let $\mu=\exp\left(\int x\ dx\right)= \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$. So now
$$ 
\mu\frac{d}{dx}[y]+\mu xy=c\mu
$$
$$ 
\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\frac{d}{dx}[y]+ \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)xy=c\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
$$
$$ 
\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\frac{d}{dx}[y]+ \frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right]y=c\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
$$
$$ 
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)y\right]=c\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)
$$
$$ 
d\left[\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)y\right]=c\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\ dx
$$
$$ 
\int d\left[\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)y\right]=c\int \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\ dx
$$
$$ 
\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)y+C=c\int \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\ dx
$$
$$ 
\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)y=c\int \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\ dx+C
$$
$$ 
y=\frac{c\int \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\ dx+C}{\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}
$$
Note that the above integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.